# How to prevent php replace stop on space?

Tags: php, replace, space

I have function like WIKI link

```
function bbcode($text)
{
  $patterns = array
  (
    '|\[\[(.*?)\|(.*?)\]\]|i',
  );
  $replacements = array
  (
    '<a href=?word=\1>\2</a>',
  );
  $text = str_replace("\n", '<br>', trim($text));
  $text = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);
  return $text;
}
```

But when I use f.e.

[[bla bla|text text]]

my link looks:

mypage.php?word=bla

but I want

mypage.php?word=bla bla

where is problem with this string "bla bla" with space? How to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

```
'<a href=?word=\1>\2</a>'
```

Should be

```
'<a href="?word=\1">\2</a>'
```

As without spaces, this will have the HTML parser assume you're defining attribute "bla" on the anchor.

Keep in mind that this is a basic example, and this implementation is vulnerable to XSS exploits if you haven't already sanitised the `$bbcode` input with htmlspecialchars() et al.

Comment: Not exactly - I used it without " to prevent double occurence to be connect together (like [[bla1]], [[bla2]] as word=bla1]], [[bla2 ). Is there another way to correctly arragne it ?